# sans-serif-light with "fake bold"

Tags: android

I have set up the following theme for my app:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

Therefor when I create a `TextView` I get the "roboto light" font which I want. Some `TextView`s however, I would like to set the `textStyle="bold"` attribute but it doesn't work since the light font doesn't have a "native" (?) bold variant.

On the other side if I programmatically use the `setTypeface` method I could get a bold font:

```
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

*This font is derived from the roboto light and looks really good.*

---

I would like to have **this bold light font** but I wonder what the most elegant way to do it is.

1. Can it be done solely using xml?
2. What is the best implementation if I need to create a "`BoldTextView extends TextView`"?

Comment: Lollipop supports `Bold` for `sans-serif-light`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a class for it:

```
public class FakeBoldTextView extends TextView {

    public FakeBoldTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setTypeface(getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
    }

    public FakeBoldTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setTypeface(getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
    }

    public FakeBoldTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setTypeface(getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
    }

}
```

And using it in XML like this:

```
<the.package.name.FakeBoldTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Example string" />
```